# mysql: calling a store procedure and receiving an error. which command caused that error?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I wrote a long stored procedure, when I call it i receive the following error:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

is there a way to tell which command in that stored procedure caused the error ?

Comment: Do you have the SQL Statement for the procedure you could post?

Comment: i want to know in general how to pinpoint when an error comes from a specific line in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a select statement at multiple points in your procedure.  Doing this, you can pinpoint the spot that your procedure fails.  Just place select statements before and after the spots you think might be failing and narrow down until you find the problem.  Before moving to production you can comment out or remove those statements.

Comment: awesome!!! thanks a lot!!!! most efficient way to know where the problems occurred. i started looking for 3rd party applications to debug stored procedures, you just saved me some money :)